# How to launch Youtube when clicking on an embedded video in my Android WebView

Tags: android

I have a webview which displays some HTML, and includes embedded YouTube videos. The videos are wrapped in an iframe tag and I have setJavascriptEnabled(true) in my Java file, so the video can play in the WebView. However, I would like to be able to launch Youtube when the user clicks the video.

Other posts on SO suggested that I parse out the video ID's and start an intent. However, this seems pretty tedious considering there can be multiple videos. In addition, I'm not sure how to set the iframe to clickable to listen for a click event.

Any suggestions?